# subsetting from a fully vectorized function in R?

Tags: r, list, function, vectorization, integral

I have written the `Vectorize`d **"main" function** below which `list`s three objects: `BF10`, `p.value` and `d`.

I'm wondering WHY when saving the "main" function call as an object like `b` (*see below*), then I can NOT subset `BF10`, `p.value` or `d` from `b`?

That is, after running the **main function**, when I when I run:

```
b = BF.d.pvalue(t = c(2.46, 3.21), n1 = c(20, 30), n2 = c(20, NA))
b$BF10   ;  b$p.value   ;   b$d  ## None of these return anything !!!
```

**Here is the "main" function:**

```
BF.d.pvalue = Vectorize(function(t, n1, n2 = NA, scale = sqrt(2)/2){

      options(warn = -1)  
      N = ifelse(is.na(n2), n1, (n1*n2)/(n1+n2))
     df = ifelse(is.na(n2), n1 - 1, (n1 + n2) - 2)
      d = t / sqrt(N)

     H1 = integrate(function(delta)dcauchy(delta, 0, scale)*dt(t, df, delta*sqrt(N)), -Inf, Inf)[[1]]
     H0 = dt(t, df)
   BF10 = H1/H0
p.value = 2*(1-pt(abs(t), df))

cbind(BF10 = BF10, p.value = p.value, d = d)

}, vectorize.args = c("t", "n1", "n2", "scale"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mapply` does simplification by default. Here result has been simplified to a matrix. You can do

```
b["BF10", ]
b["p.value", ]
b["d", ]
```

Although you can set `SIMPLIFY = FALSE`, but the result is a nested list.

If you want something like a list / data frame where you can use `$`, how about

```
b <- data.frame(t(b))
```